# How to stop DIV element from getting pushed down in table?

Tags: css, html, alignment

Any clue how to stop a DIV element from getting pushed down in a table?

Here's the page: http://www.panabee.com/domain-name-generator/healthy%20food

As you can see, the "Variations" DIV element in the left-hand side is pushed down unnaturally.  It should be top aligned with the "Ask for help..." image, but for some reason the presence of the image pushes down the Variations" DIV element.  If I replace the image with a little text, the top boxes in the two columns are again top aligned.

Any clues?

Thanks!

P.S. Feel free to offer feedback/suggestions on the site, too!  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add to your css `vertical-align:top;` for `#main_box`
[image]

Comment: i did this in the table row and table cell ... but this is also needed in the css?

Comment: @crashalot in your css file you have #main_box, you need to add `vertical-align:top;` to it. Check screenshot i posted above

Comment: awesome, thanks, @Hussein!  i love SO!  btw, any suggestions/feedback on the site?

Comment: looks promising. Colors are easy on the eyes. I know it's not complete yet. keep working on it :-).

Answer (score 2):

add  `vertical-align: top;` for `#main_box`. Because you have the reset, the `td` takes  `vertical-align: baseline;` and override the `"valign=top"` in html.

Comment: i did this in the table row and table cell ... but this is also needed in the css?

Comment: It was needed for the `#main_box`. I explained you above that the reset.css has `vertical-align: baseline;` for the `td` and this overrides the html.

Comment: ahh gotcha, i was under the impression that inline styles override all other styles.  is this a special case for the vertical-align property, or is it wrong that inline styles override all else?  i wish i could split the answer between you and hussein ... sorry about that. :(

Comment: The `valign='top'` is not an inline style but a html attribute of of tables. About the answer, I can't understand why someone answers the same thing after 5 minutes...anyway, anyone can do whatever thinks it's right :)

Answer (score 0):

The anchor `a` tag in your right side bar (inside the ask_for_help div) has a `vertical-align` of `baseline`. Remove that and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add to your css `vertical-align:top`; for `#main_box`